# Binding variable not available Jenkins SQS

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-sqs

I have a jenkins job that uses a pipeline script. The script is shared between the dev and production jenkins. So i need to make decision based on the parameter that is configured in jenkins job ( Through this project is parametrized option)

The master jenkins job shall be triggered manually or by sending SQS message. 
When the Jenkins is triggered through SQS, I am not getting the stage that is configured in jenkins job in the pipeline

Below the code snippet. I am getting Binding error in the withEnv step.

```
stage('Code Merge') {
    withEnv([ 
                "STAGE=${STAGE}"
        ]) {
            echo "Printing Stage :: ${STAGE}"
```

Please can someone help me a way to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue using `env.STAGE` instead of `${STAGE}`.

The `${STAGE}` strictly ensures if the parameter is present, `env.<paramNAme>` is used when you want the parameters to be optional